# Writing an integral in terms of special functions

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, special-functions, elliptic-functions

I would like to find an expression for the following integrals, using special functions or otherwise; I suspect they can be written in terms of elliptic functions but I've played with it for a while and haven't arrived at anything useful. The integrals are:

$$
\mathcal{I}_1 = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\alpha^2(\beta^2-\cos^2\xi)}}\frac{\xi \cos\xi}{\sqrt{\beta^2-\cos^2\xi}} d\xi
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{I}_2 = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{4}\sin^2\xi}}\frac{\xi \cos\xi}{\sqrt{\beta^2-\sin^2\xi}} d\xi 
$$

I would be happy with expressions for the perhaps simpler form:

$$
\mathcal{I}_a = \int \frac{\sin^{-1}\left(B\cos\xi\right)}{\sqrt{A^2-\sin^2\xi)}} d\xi
$$
and
$$
\mathcal{I}_b = \int \frac{\sin^{-1}\left(B\sin\xi\right)}{\sqrt{A^2-\sin^2\xi)}} d\xi
$$

Answer (score 2):

Since $\cos^2(x) = 1 - \sin^2(x)$ both $I_1$ and $I_2$ can be rewritten as some constant multiple of an antiderivative of the form:
\begin{align}
I(a,b) =\int \frac{x\cos(x)}{\sqrt{a^2-\sin^2(x)}\sqrt{b^2 - \sin^2(x)}} \,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
for some constants $a,b$. Now, from the definition of the [Elliptic integral of the First Kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) we see that
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{b}F\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right), \frac{a}{b}\right) =\frac{1}{b} \int_0^{\sin\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\right)} \frac{\mathrm{d}t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{a^2}{b^2}t^2}\sqrt{1-t^2}} \overset{u = at}{=} \int_0^{x} \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}\sqrt{b^2-u^2}}
\end{align}
So by taking the substitution $u = \sin(x)$ we get
$$
\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{a^2-\sin^2(x)}\sqrt{b^2 - \sin^2(x)}} \mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{b}F\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{a}\right), \frac{a}{b}\right)
$$
And thus
\begin{align}
I(a,b)\overset{\text{I.B.P.}}{=}& x\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{a^2-\sin^2(x)}\sqrt{b^2 - \sin^2(x)}} \,\mathrm{d}x - \int\left(\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{a^2-\sin^2(x)}\sqrt{b^2 - \sin^2(x)}} \,\mathrm{d}x\right)\mathrm{d}x\\
 =&\frac{x}{b}F\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{a}\right), \frac{a}{b}\right) - \frac{1}{b}\int F\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{\sin(x)}{a}\right), \frac{a}{b}\right)\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}
And now, even for the simple case of $a=1$ and $b=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ the [antiderivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BEllipticF%5Bx%2C+2%5D%2C+x%5D) in the previous equation already involves hypergeometric functions and generalized hypergeometric functions, so I don't have much hope for a possible closed form for the general case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response; I had previously obtained the final line in your answer but it's not what I'm looking for as it's just replacing one tricky integral with another.

Some very similar integrals appear in http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/IntegralsIndefinite/IndefInt.html with closed form expressions so that is what I'm looking for.